# What happens to the metric when we normalize the basis?

Tags: vector-bundles, spherical-geometry

Here is an Example in Euclidean 3-space: When using spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ with $\theta$ and $\phi$ the polar and azimuthal angles, respectively: a natural basis for these coordinates given the metric 
$$(g_{ij}) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & r^2 & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & r^2 \sin^2{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}$$
is $$\vec{e_{r}} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}, \\
\vec{e_\theta} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}, \\ 
\vec{e_\phi} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
which have the following lengths:
$$||\vec{e_{r}}|| = 1, ||\vec{e_{\theta}}|| =r, ||\vec{e_{\phi}}|| = r \sin{\theta}.$$

Similarly for the analogously defined dual basis:
$$||\vec{e^{r}}|| = 1, ||\vec{e^{\theta}}|| =\frac{1}{r}, ||\vec{e^{\phi}}|| = \frac{1}{r \sin{\theta}}.$$

In physics it is common to define a new, unit basis (hence-force the hatted basis): 
$$\vec{e_{r}} = \hat{e_r}, \\ \\ \\ \\ \frac{\vec{e_{\theta}}}{r} =\hat{e_\theta}, \\ \\ \\ \\ \frac{\vec{e_{\phi}}}{r \sin{\theta}} = \hat{e_\phi}$$

The question then arises as to what the dual basis is for this normalized coordinate system, labelled $\hat{e^r}, \hat{e^\theta}, \hat{e^\phi}$ (hats for consistency, but not necessarily norm of $1$): $$\hat{e^\theta} = g^{\theta \theta}\hat{e_\theta} = g^{\theta \theta}\frac{\vec{e_\theta}}{r} = \frac{\vec{e^\theta}}{r}, || \hat{e^\theta}|| = \frac{1}{r^2}$$
$$\hat{e^\phi} = g^{\phi \phi}\hat{e_\phi} = g^{\phi \phi}\frac{\vec{e_\phi}}{r \sin{\theta}} = \frac{\vec{e^\phi}}{r \sin{\theta}}, || \hat{e^\phi}|| = \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2{\theta}}$$

Consider the vector in the natural basis $$\vec{V} = \begin{pmatrix}
a \\ \\ b \\ \\ c
\end{pmatrix} .$$ This same vector in the normalized basis is:
$$\hat{V} = \begin{pmatrix}
a \\ \\ br \\ \\ cr \sin(\theta) 
\end{pmatrix} .$$

Given that a metric is defined by $g_{ij} = \langle e_i,e_j \rangle $ we can see our change of basis has preserved the inner product, i.e. $\vec{V}^2 = \hat{V}^2$ with our new metric, $$(\hat{g_{ij}}) = (\delta_{ij}) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & 1 & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}.$$ However if we do this analysis with the dual basis we do not find the inverse metric, but another metric: $$(\hat{g^{ij}}) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & \frac{1}{r^4} & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{r^4 \sin^4{\theta}}
\end{pmatrix} \neq (\delta^{ij})$$

This set of $2$ not inverse metrics for vectors and co-vectors respectively, is the crux of my confusion. Is this somehow okay? If not, is there something I have done incorrectly here, computationally or definitionally? My question more broadly is: how does going from a natural basis which is implied from the metric, to a normalized vector basis, in general affect the induced dual space and metric?

Comment: This seemed to be a bit lower level for MathOverflow but I posted on stackexchange and got no answer there

Comment: I think that the terminology you use is a bit confusing. The term basis  is used   only when we perform  *linear* changes of coordinates. For nonlinear coordinates the terminology is that of (moving) frame, i.e., a collection of vector fields such that, at each point, they form a basis of the corresponding tangent space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric tensor is defined from the basis, $g_{ij} = \vec{e}_{i} \cdot \vec{e}_{j} $. If you change the basis from the $\vec{e}_{i} $ to the $\hat{e}_{i} $, then you also change the metric tensor from $g_{ij} $ to the corresponding $\hat{g}_{ij} $. You can't calculate the new $\hat{e}^{i} $ using the old metric $g^{ij} $, as you do above; instead, it has to be $\hat{e}^{i} = \hat{g}^{ij} \hat{e}_{j} $. The dual basis should satisfy $\hat{e}^{i} \cdot \hat{e}_{j} = \delta^{i}_{j} $.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me. I do have a follow up question if you have the time: in this answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618031/del-operator-nabla-in-spherical-co-ordinate-system) ∇ is derived for spherical coordinates. However in my case $\hat{∇}$ would have no pre-factors, since all of my dual vectors would be of length 1. This is not at all the usual ∇ operator found in, say electrodynamics textbooks, where that hatted cooridnate basis is certainly the one being used.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: (revising my previous comment - I was being a bit too cautious) ... 
The notation in typical electrodynamics textbooks isn't very transparent with respect to the issues you're raising. Indeed, the hatted basis vectors are used, but the unhatted coordinates! If you replace also the unhatted coordinates with the hatted ones in the usual expression, then it seems to me things are consistent with your way of looking at it.